# Get value from XML code where attribute has particular value [using XElement]

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am attempting to retrieve values from certain nodes in an XML response by using XElement where the attribute value is "id=x".

This is what the XML response looks like.

```
<customfields>
<group id="6" title="Help Desk Ticket Categories" displayorder="1">
<field id="73" title="Second level classification" type="6" name="zscyz3a30h1q"><![CDATA[-- unassigned --]]></field>
</group>
<group id="9" title="For CS" displayorder="4">
<field id="82" title="CS Root Cause Classification " type="6" name="pye19ntzyp8v"><![CDATA[--Unassigned--]]></field>
<field id="84" title="Staff Responsible" type="6" name="7gy8bfu8tidv"><![CDATA[-- unassigned --]]></field>
<field id="93" title="Customer Package" type="6" name="fxk9rqtlw0fa"><![CDATA[--Unassigned--]]></field>
</group>
<group id="2" title="Client Info" displayorder="3">
<field id="5" title="Customer Name" type="1" name="77004d0323"><![CDATA[BigG]]></field>
<field id="17" title="Account Number" type="1" name="d1abccc1a0" /><![CDATA[123]]></field>
<field id="16" title="Contact Name" type="1" name="93d2b9adf1" /><![CDATA[george]]></field>
<field id="13" title="Phone No." type="1" name="0aa31be4b8" /><![CDATA[456]]></field>
</group>
</customfields>
```

This is the code I'm using now (which works), but I'd rather retrieve values for *field with "id"="5"* rather than have the value retrieved through a descendant index.

```
    XElement root = XElement.Parse(GetTicketCustomFields(ticketID));
    kCustomer = (string)(from el in root.Descendants("field") select el).ElementAt(4);
    kAccountNumber = (string)(from el in root.Descendants("field") select el).ElementAt(5);
    kName = (string)(from el in root.Descendants("field") select el).ElementAt(6);
    kPhone = (string)(from el in root.Descendants("field") select el).ElementAt(7);
```

Thanks for

Answer (score 0):

I would use XPath

```
var root = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var accountNumber = root.XPathSelectElement("//field[@id='17']").Value;
```

or

```
var accountNumber = root.XPathSelectElement("//field[@title='Account Number']").Value;
```

Using Linq2Xml is also possible

```
var accountNumber =  root.Descendants("field")
                    .FirstOrDefault(F => F.Attribute("id").Value == "17")
                    .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath as @L.B. suggests.

If you're using Visual Studio there's a plugin written by yours truly which can help you find the XPath of a given element or attribute, to get you on your way: [XPath Information](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c06c7b10-41c3-4aa9-8707-570eb9d879e6)